# Replacing all of the characters in between two html tags with whitespace in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm trying to write some code to replace every character between two html tags (`<del>` tag to be specific) with a whitespace, but I'm struggling with the PHP string methods.
An example of how the code should operate: if the initial string is `"blahblah<del>blahblah</del>blahblah"`, ideally the result would be `"blahblah        blahblah"` with 8 whitespaces (for the 8 character length of the piece between the `<del>` tags) in between the two `blahblah`'s

I'm writing this code for a pretty basic server, so I don't have access to any extra libraries/services like Node,etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: The text between the `<del>` tags is variable in length. It's not always 8 characters long.

Comment: You are not limited to a regex here. You can actually do that with DOM, get the nodes you need, and replace them with a text node containing the same amount of spaces as the length of the node value.

Comment: why don't you use js for this??

Comment: This is being processed for a SQL query in a PHP connector script, so I wanted the code to also work in PHP. I suppose if worst comes to worst I can use js

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace_callback` to pull the content between the `<del>` and `</del>`. You then can use that return to count the number of characters inside and replace them in the original string. Something like this should do it:

```
$string = 'blahblah<del>blahblah</del>blahblah';
echo preg_replace_callback('~<del>(.*?)</del>~', function($match) {
        $replace = str_repeat(' ', mb_strlen($match[1]));
        return $replace;
}, $string);
```

https://3v4l.org/ht22A

Comment: Please make sure you use the update. I forgot `preg_replace` was already running so using the `use` doubled the output.